# GCP / Finding Zone Resource Status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, zones

I'm using the Google Cloud Platform for a project of mine and utilize preemptibile instances, meaning my instances restart once every 24h. Every few weeks I encounter an issue where my instances are all offline and can't boot up as all the resources in that zone (us-east1) are occupied.

I've tried looking all over for a tool but can't find any so I decided to ask here: is there a way to see which zones are full and which aren't? It doesn't matter if it's a website or a command, I just need something to look at to determine which zone to move my instances to while my main zone is full and possibly hook into that and automate it.

Also, the following command doesn't work as it doesn't provide the resource status of each zone.

```
gcloud compute zones list
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can't get that information.

Comment: Why not? It'd be useful for many different cases and I can't think of any security issues it would cause.